# detecting textbox change when changing the content programmatically 

Tags: jquery

I have a textbox that's linked to a jquery event handler like this:

```
$('#SomeDiv').on({

   mouseenter: ....
   mouseleave: ....
   blur: ....
   keyup: function() { HandlerForKeyUp($(this)); } ,
   change: function() { HandlerForKeyUp($(this)); } 

}, '.MyTextBoxes');
```

Basically, `HandlerForKeyUp` is a function that shows a counter of the number of letters in the textbox. It works fine when the user is typing.

However, if I write this:

```
$('#SomeTextBox').val(SomeValue);
```

the HandlerForKeyUp function doesn't trigger, even thought I have the `change` event mapped out in the `.on` handler and SomeTextBox is of class `MyTextBoxes` and reacts to all other events. Basically, if the user types the counter works but if I set the value of the textbox at runtime the counter function doesn't trigger.

Any idea on how I could change this?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: If You do it in Your code, you may just invoke tthe handling function manually after data is changed.

Comment: Try triggering any of the events you've bound with http://api.jquery.com/trigger/ after the val update.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to fire the change event manually.

`$('#SomeTextBox').val(SomeValue).change();`

Comment: Since .change was designed to capture the change event and trigger the same function as the .keyup event, I just removed .change and wrote $('#SomeTextBox').val(SomeValue).keyup(); Thanks for the suggestion!