# Detect change in textbox value whose value changes on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

I have the following piece of code:

```js
$(".select").click(function(){
  $("input").val($(this).text()).change();
});
$("input").change(function(){
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
<button class="select">1</button>
<button class="select">2</button>
<button class="select">3</button>
<button class="select">4</button>
```

Here, when I select the **same** value by clicking a `<button>`, the `.change()` function gets fired anyways which makes it no different from any other function i.e. ruins its specialization of being triggered only on change in value.

A [**similar question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850310/detecting-textbox-change-when-changing-the-content-programmatically) exists on SO, but it does not give any answer to this issue.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: What is the issue? You do not what to trigger the change if the value has not changed? So add a check before you set the value. If(value is not the same) do XXX

Comment: then what's the purpose of `.change()` if **I'm** the one who is supposed to check the value?

Comment: UM, you change the value manually. Even when you call change and it would check, it would NOT know the previous value. You could write a custom fn method that sets the value and does it for you, but any way you do it, you will need to do a check.

Comment: So, does that mean I can't detect the change in the textbox (in this case), solely using `.change()` method without using any conditions?

Answer (score 1):

That's what `.change()` method without passing a handler does, triggering a `change` event. You should compare the values and trigger the event conditionally.

The `change` event is not fired when you change the value of an input programmatically. So as you are triggering the event manually (*by using the `change` method*), you should check the values yourself before triggering the event.

Comment: then what's the purpose of `.change()` if **I'm** the one who is supposed to check the value?

Comment: Yes. That's right. If I remove that, it won't get triggered at all.

Can't I detect change using `.change()` method and avoid condition checks?

Comment: If I'm not calling `.change()` method *explicitly*, it **won't** get fired *implicitly*. I hope you get my point now.

Comment: @theScorpion Unfortunately no. Detection needs condition(s) after all.

Answer (score 0):

Add if statement and it will work according to your need

```js
$(".select").click(function(){
if($("input").val() != $(this).text())
  $("input").val($(this).text()).change();
});
$("input").change(function(){
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
<button class="select">1</button>
<button class="select">2</button>
<button class="select">3</button>
<button class="select">4</button>
```

Comment: what I was looking for, was to **avoid** any condition checks and detect change solely using `.change()` method.

Comment: Then change() is meant to change the content no matter what your text box contains, the same text or not, it will perform its function, you have to add check statement

Comment: That's not right. `.change()` is used for detecting change in an `<input>`. Here's an example: http://jsbin.com/lecuyimiko/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Yeah, you are right i was too lame, my intentions were that if you click on your button then the text will change inside your textbox no matter if you have same text or not and it will trigger the .change() function